# Invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript - C++

Tags: c++, function, vector

I've this error when I try to save a number into my vector...

```
Invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
```

The code is:

```
class Elemento{
private:
    int Nodo;

public:
         Elemento(){};
         ~Elemento(){};
    void SetNumero(int x)    {  Nodo = x;  };
    int  GetNumero()         {  return Nodo; };
};    


class MagicSquare{
private:
    int    N;                             
    int    Possibili_N;                  
    int    Magic_Constant;                

    vector<Elemento> Square(int Possibili_N);    

public:
    MagicSquare()                   {    };
    ~MagicSquare()                  {    };

    void  Set_N(int x)              { N = x; };
    void  Set_PossibiliN(int x)     { Possibili_N = x; };
    void  Set_MagicConstant(int x)  { Magic_Constant = x; };

    . . .

    void SetSquare(int i, int x)    { Square[i].SetNumero(x); }; // got error here
    int  GetSquare(int i)           { return Square[i].GetNumero(); }; // got error here
};
```

I've got error whenever I use Square[i].method()...

I call a method that pass the index in the Square and the value to put in `Elemento->Nodo`, but I've to use a public method to access to private `Nodo`. The same with the GET. I want to get the value for displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have declared `Square` as a function, not a variable.

Instead, declare `vector<Elemento> Square;` and initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: So, How can I initialize it in the constructor? I have to calculate before N, Possible_N and MagicCostant and then I can dimension the vector...

Comment: @FedericoCuozzo you can use [`vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) if you have to compute something first.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `Square` as a function, not a variable.  So `Square[i]` is not valid.
Change

```
vector<Elemento> Square(int Possibili_N);
```

to

```
vector<Elemento> Square;
```

or call it using

```
Square(i)
```

if it is actually a function.

If you change it to a variable, you need to be sure to initialize it properly, preferably in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your line `vector<Elemento> Square(int Possibili_N);` is know as [`C++ most vexing parse`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Instead of declaring a member variable, as intended, you are declaring a function taking an `int` and returning a vector.

Instead, setup the member vector (and all other member variables) in the constructor initialization list:

```
class MagicSquare{
private:
    int N;
    int Possibili_N;
    int Magic_Constant;
    vector<Elemento> Square;

public:
    MagicSquare( int n, int p, int m ) :
        N( n ),
        Possibili_N( p ),
        Magic_Constant( m ),
        Square( p ) {
    }
...
```